# Typing : def + TAB to insert a definition in a Ruby file., I get <def> </def> (in VSCode)

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, tabs, tags, command

When I type **def + TAB** to insert a definition in a ruby file in VSCode, I get:

```
<def></def>
```

I am sure a week ago, before installing a bunch of new extensions, I could type **def + TAB** and get :

```
def 

end
```

I wonder if that might come from an extension that I installed this last days. The thing is that I Installed a bunch of new extensions. I uninstalled all the new ones and kept to ones I've already got, but cannot get back to a nice def + tab as before. It keeps transforming def as an html tag :

```
<def></def>
```

I don't know how to get back things how they were. I still don't know what else I might have jumbled. Can someone tell me if somewhere we can configure the action of ** def + TAB** ?

I am working on VSCode with Ruby and I have the following extensions still working on it :
Ruby, SQLite, SQLite Viewer, Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer, VSCode Great Icons, VSCode Ruby.

I just uninstalled the other extensions I have since a few days :
Code Runner, Code Spell Checker, endwise, ESLint, GitHub Theme, HTML to CSS autocompletion, Jupyter, Jupyter Cell Tags, Jupyter Keymap, Jupyter Notebook Renderers, Jupyter Slide Show, Live Share, Lorem ipsum, Markdown All in One, Paste and Indent, Path Intellisense, Pylance, Python, Python Type Hint, Tailwind CSS IntelliSense, Todo MD.

[I add here a picture I mentioned in my first comment to @anothermh.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwSPT.png)

Comment: what does the suggestion menu look like right before you press tab? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: I have no suggestion at all when I press Tab, (in a .rb file of course), it directly writes for "def" Tab `<def></def>` and for "if Tab `<iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe> `.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing are [Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). Managing snippets can be tough because there are built-in snippets, snippets you get from extensions and user-defined snippets. User-defined snippets can be profile-level or workspace-level which can make them hard to track down.

It's possible to [disable snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_can-i-remove-snippets-from-intellisense) by clicking *Hide from IntelliSense* but you have to know *which* snippet you want to disable first.

I suggest an extension called [Snippets Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RandomFractalsInc.snippets-viewer) that allows you to view all of your snippets which will make it a little easier to track down which one is causing the issue, then you can disable it.

Comment: Thanks @anothermh for your feedback.

The Snippets Viewer extension is very interesting. I loaded it and strangely I have snippets for many languages and have snippets for embedded Ruby .erb, but not Ruby in .rb. I don't get why, I did disable all the non-Ruby extensions and kept my Ruby extensions. 
I saw that I can get my result with the ^Space shortcut, but I would like to be able to just do Tab.

Comment: I also uninstalled my Ruby extension and then restarted my computer and reinstalled it. Now I have a Ruby folder that appears in the "snippets Viewer:Snippets" extension tab (see picture), but "def" for example does not appear and for "if" that appears, it still does not work. When I type "if" and then Tab, I get tags that look like html. 


  ```<def></def> #using Tab

  def method_name #using ^Space
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe> #using Tab
  end```

Comment: I read the whole article on the page you shared the links to and so I tried to create snippets for .rb, following the path to "configure user snippets" but it's only ruby.json that comes up when I type RUBY and .erb when I type rb .

I have the impression that an extension has come and messed up everything.
I'm thinking that maybe there are other things that have been messed up that I don't see yet. 
I wonder if I should reset VSCode completely. But I don't know if it will disturb anything to my configuration with the Terminal...?

Comment: Regarding extensions, I made sure to install extensions that were well-supported with enough users. Are there any recommendations to follow to avoid installing extensions that disturb our configuration?

Comment: At this point you’ve dug yourself in deeper. Delete your VSCode profile and start over.

Comment: **FOUND THE SOLUTION** :  I finally reconfigured VSCode following this video tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lT56Ipom6_A&lc=Ugxx1znXN9kEovwwZoF4AaABAg&ab_channel=CodewithSusan) by @codewithsusan.  I saved and pasted back the settings.json file line by line, checking each time the effects of each line on my issue. I found some code that actually messed my VSCode (!!!  )  between ** here :  `"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "erb": "html", **"ruby": "html"**
    },`.

Comment: I removed the `"ruby": "html"` and after installing back my extensions (not all, but the ones I am sure to use) I got back my VSCode working as before.